# I need help in PHP array

Tags: php

My Array is -

```
Array
(
    [0] => accordion
    [1] => bars
 
)
```

I need to access this array in a simple way.
Is it possible to like the below system?

```
if(isset($array['accordion'])){
// do something...
}
```

Comment: Arrays have keys and values. In your case the keys are 0 and 1, i.e. `$array[0]` and `$array[1]`.  Please read the documentation for arrays for more info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access the array elements using a key.

The array in php can look something like this:

```
$my_array = ["foo", "bar"];

// These values of this array are accessed using the key - the numeric index of the key, where 0 is the first item in the array.

$my_array[0]; // points to the value "foo"
$my_array[1]; // points to the value "bar"
```

Or you can access the values of the array using named keys. Like this:

```
$my_array = [
   "name" => "John",
   "lastname" => "Doe"
];

// Then you approach the values of this array as follows:
$my_array['name'];  // points to the value "John"
$my_array['lastname']; // points to the value "Doe"
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to test if the array has a specific value.